# Excel Vlookup LEFT #N/A issue on just a few cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Good morning everyone,
I normally find vlookups in Excel easy, but in this case my formula works on a long list of cells except for just a couple of them which has left me stumped since it works otherwise.

Here is what I have written into cell B8:
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A8, 1), $F$8:$G$10, 2, 0)

In column A there are some codes such as XRK156, so I'm taking the X and looking it up in a small table that looks like:
X   2
Y   9
Z   1

Whenever the code starts with Y and Z, the formula works perfectly and returns the 9 or 1, but there are a couple that start with X and it gives me #N/A on those. I've checked the data type and X,Y,Z are all 'general'. Whenever people have Vlookup Left issues, it can often be resolved with --LEFT(A8, 1) or LEFT(A8, 1)*1, but these don't fix it and as I said, it works for almost everything except just the X.

Much appreciated if you have any ideas.

Comment: Check two things, first check on those that fail that the 1 character is not a space or other unprintable character.  Second make sure your lookup table that the `X` does not have any other spaces or other unprintable characters.

Comment: Thanks so much - that's the correct solution. It had a space after it. I really appreciate you answering because I'd read so many web pages and couldn't figure out why the formula didn't work, and the problem is in the table I was supplied.